# PHP - Submit URL

Tags: php, url, submit, decode

If i submit my code i get aways problems with the URL, its simply encode my url informations but it should not.

Is there a way to turn the URL encode (after submit) off?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$test = "https://www.saferpay.com/vt2/Pay.aspx?DATA=%3CIDP+ALLOWCOLLECT%3D%22no%22+EXPIRATION%3D%222XX0613+15%3A01%3A44%22+LANGID%3D%22de%22+DESCRIPTION%3D%22XXXX%22+BACKLINK%3D%22https%3A%2F%XXXX.com%2Fcheckout_confirmation.php%22+AMOUNT%3D%221195%22+ACCOUNTID%3D%22XX88-17776195%22+DELIVERY%3D%22no%22+XDNAME%3D%22yes%22+SUCCESSLINK%3D%22https%3A%2F%2FXXXXX.com%2Fcheckout_process.php%22+ORDERID%3D%22F554815DEUT%22+CURRENCY%3D%22EUR%22+USERNOTIFY%3D%22XXXX%40XXXX.de%22+FAILLINK%3D%22https%3A%2F%2FXXX.com%2Fcheckout_payment.php%3Fpayment_error%3Dsaferpay%22+MSGTYPE%3D%22PayInit%22+AUTOCLOSE%3D%220%22+KEYID%3D%220-95488-7a22b1f5755c01e0bb7b2d66f8bbfea1%22+XDY%3D%22yes%22+TOKEN%3D%22e5864ffdf23501e310b07366030f24fa%22+NOTIFYURL%3D%22https%3A%2F%2FXXX-shop.com%2Fmylog.php%22%2F%3E&SIGNATURE=1E4C05F995F632ECD50985D1A4A2A96A9734BA886FB88BC8B086503E19BD419623DB047B499FEC0C8F015EE475A08224B258E7B1649888F2A4B274495F13CAC0";
$test2 = "\"http://localhost/XXXX/index.php?menuaction=etemplate.editor.edit&name=projectmanager.list\"";
$test_array = explode('?', $test);

$url = $test_array[0];
$params = $test_array[1];

$params_array = explode('&', $params);

$par1 = $params_array[0];
$par2 = $params_array[1];

$par1_array = explode('=', $par1);
$par2_array = explode('=', $par2);

$val1 = htmlspecialchars ($par1_array[1]);
$val2 = $par2_array[1];

?>

<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $par1_array[0]; ?>" value="<?php echo $val1; ?>" > 
  <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $par2_array[0]; ?>" value="<?php echo $val2; ?>" > 

</form>
```

Comment: why not `urldecode()` ?

Comment: Where should i use it, i tried it but it did not help

Comment: you sure `$test = urldecode('url here')` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `urldecode()` on `$par1_array[1]` and `$par2_array[1]`

Comment: Try send without `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. It also could not work if you try send request from another domain (secure settings).